# user selection Combobox then to Labels according to database MS Access c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox

i have the following code below and what im trying to do is on the comboBox there is "ID" from my database and this ID represents every survey detail that Admin used to create so when the user goes to view the survey they click on the survey number in comboBox and the labels will change according to the database. I tried it with the below code but unfortunatley all it seems to do is grab a random one, if someone could help that would be amazing. It doesnt have to be like below, just as long as it works,

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_newsurvey ";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string name = reader["txtname"].ToString();
            lblname.Text = name;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use a `WHERE` clause on your query to get data from your database based on the `ComboBox Selected Item`

Comment: @AndreiSolero so something like this? string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_newsurvey WHERE ID= ' " + comboBoxID.Text + "'";

Comment: Yeah, that's how you retrieve data from database using combobox

Comment: But also, I suggest you use a parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: can you show me how you would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to search data from database using Combobox

> I use parameterized query to avoid `SQL Injection`

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_newsurvey WHERE [ColumnName] = @ComboBoxValue";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComboBoxValue", comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString())
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read() == true)
        {
            string name = reader["txtname"].ToString();
            lblname.Text = name;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```